# How do i use my self.username as MDToolbar title

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I wan to use the username that the people use to log in as the title of my MDToolbar.
Can somebody help me do it . I use builder. load so i dont know how i would do it

This is my python code.

```
class GipApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        self.username = "unknown"
        self.usernameKV = "unknown"
        return screen


    def verify(self, username, password):
        if username != "" and password != "":
            for row in MySqlNames:
                if row[0].strip() == username:
                    sql = "SELECT Password from ID191774_6itn1project7.Users where Username = %s "
                    mycursor.execute(sql, (username))
                    TestPassword = mycursor.fetchall()
                    for row3 in TestPassword:
                        if row3[0].strip() == password:
                            dialog = MDDialog(title="Login successful")
                            dialog.open()
                            self.username = username
                            GipApp.get_running_app().root.current = 'main'

                        if row3[0] != password:
                            dialog = MDDialog(title="Passwords is not correct.")
                            dialog.open()
        else:
            dialog = MDDialog(title="Fill in the empty text boxes")
            dialog.open()
```

I want to use the string value of self.username from in `verify()`.

This is my kivy code where is want to use the username as the MDToolbar title.

```
<MainScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'mountains.jpg'
    name: 'main'
    NavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            Screen:    
                orientation: 'vertical'
                MDToolbar:
                    title: "??????????"
                    left_action_items:[["menu",lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
                    elevation :12
                    pos_hint:{"center_x": .5, "center_y": .95}
                MDRoundFlatButton:
                    text: 'Start Object identify here'
                    text_color:(1, 1, 1, 1)
                    size: 110, 110
                    on_release: app.Yolo()
                    pos_hint:{"center_x": .35, "center_y": 0.5}
                MDRoundFlatButton:
                    text: 'Face mask tracking'
                    text_color:(1, 1, 1, 1)
                    size: 110, 110
                    
                    pos_hint:{"center_x": .65, "center_y": 0.5}
                MDLabel:
                    text:"Press esc to stop."
                    halign:'center'
                    theme_text_color:'Custom'
                    text_color:(1, 1, 1, 1)
                    font_style:'Subtitle1'
                    pos_hint:{"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.35}
                MDIconButton:
                    icon: "account"
                    pos_hint:{"center_x": .95, "center_y": .95}
                    user_font_size: "35sp"
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'account'
```

Can somebody please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give an ID to the Toolbar and then you would be able to access its attributes and change the title in python.

Here is a simple demo of the Toolbar title getting changed when the button is clicked.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
MDFloatLayout:
    MDToolbar:
        title: "MDToolbar"
        pos_hint: {"top":1}
        id: toolbar


    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Click"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
        on_release: app.change()
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def change(self):
        self.root.ids.toolbar.title = "Custom Title"

Test().run()
```

[image: Demo of changing toolbar title]